# Keyboard shortcut to open new finder window from same/current location?

Tags: finder, shortcut

Suppose we open finder and navigate to some burrowed-down folder, and then wish to open an identical finder window (i.e. from the same folder/location).

How can that be done with a keyboard shortcut (or similarly convenient method)?

I checked [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) but the closest I spotted was <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open a new finder window from the user's home directory (not the current directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for folders but not files… column view works best for this, other views have odd ideas as to which folder you really mean.

Navigate to your deeply-nested destination

Select the 'deepest' folder in the hierarchy, this will be your 'dupe point'.
Hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  then double-click the selected folder.
A brand new window will open in front, to the same location.

If you do this with a file, it will try to launch in its default app.
If you have more than one item selected before double-click, or have one item selected but double-click another… all selections will be actioned.

Comment: Just tried it, works a treat. By hitting cmd + left arrow afterwards, it navigates back to the original folder. Thank you!